# Is there a way to not show my full name on Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I want to share a document with my guild in an MMO, but for obvious reasons I don't want every single person to have knowledge of my real name. Is there a way to make it so that the name displayed is different than the account's profile name? (I'd rather not change that.)

If not, can I turn off peoples' ability to see my account name when it is viewing a document, and would make me appear instead as one of the various "Anonymous [Animal]"s?

Comment: It seems that a similar question is answered here, http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21578/how-do-i-change-my-nickname-or-display-name-on-google-docs

Comment: Yeah, it's the first hit on google so I attempted that and it's no longer valid. Unless I massively screwed up, my nickname is still not appearing as my displayed name on docs.

Comment: @Arkwolf Did you read the second answer there?

Comment: @404 Yes, I did. But that was 6 months ago, and I was wondering if anything had changed at this point. I suppose it hasn't.